# Check for Existing Saved Query in MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I need to create a saved MS Access query from within my VB.net program using OleDb.  But before I create the query I need to check and see if it already exists in the database.  If it does exist I want to update it.  How do I check for an existing query in MS Access using OleDb?

Comment: Have you ruled out attempting to create the Access query and trapping the error when it already exists?

Comment: If you are going to create the query in VBA, you could always put `On Error Resume Next` on the line before the query definition.  Then just after the query put `On Error Goto Err_Handler`.  Obviously, Err_Handler could be named differently.  This would only create the query if it doesn't exist and would not generate an error if it does exists.

Comment: @HansUp I've never done any error trapping.  Could you give a quick example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know VB.Net.  Did you try Linger's suggestions?

Comment: Ok Thanks.  Linger's suggestion is for VBA which may take a little tweaking.

Comment: I've seen `.Net` code using `try` and `catch`.  I'm guessing you want those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"If it does exist I want to update it."*

Based on the comment discussion, I understand you will execute a statement on the OleDB connection to create the query.  (In Access parlance, a `QueryDef` object.)

When the query does not already exist, the execute succeeds and you're done.

If the query does exist, the execute attempt will throw an error which you will trap in your `VB.Net` code.  At that point, you want to revise the existing query.  Unfortunately, I don't know any way to alter an existing query with OleDb.  You can however discard the existing query and re-execute your statement to create the new version.

You can execute an Access DDL statement to discard the existing query.  One of these two versions will do what you need:

1. `DROP VIEW YourQueryNameHere;`
2. `DROP PROCEDURE YourQueryNameHere;`

The first is for plain `SELECT` queries.  The second is for what Access calls "action queries": `INSERT`; `UPDATE`; `DELETE`.  A "make table" query (`SELECT <field list> INTO NewTable FROM ...`) also falls into the second (PROCEDURE) category as I recall (check to confirm if you need it).  I think a `SELECT` query with `PARAMETERS` also falls into that second category (check if needed).

Note this is a only a suggested direction.  I can't offer you `VB.Net` code.  And I'm hopeful you know or can figure how to do the required error-handling in `VB.Net`.

Comment: To my knowledge both views and procedures are `select` statements. Access calls it a view if it doesn't use any parameters (like the value of a form control), and a procedure if it does.

Comment: I like the idea of just discarding existing query and creating a new one. Easier to work around a possible 'not exist' error than to figure out how to alter a query.

Comment: @HansUp This looks like the way to go!  I'll start working on it! Thanks!